# Как сделать, чтобы с сайта можно было скачать документ?

Tags: html

Как сделать, чтобы с сайта можно было скачать документ?

Comment: Дать ссылку на документ.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
 <a href="document.doc">Скачать</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$path='where/';$file='what';
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$file\""); //указываем имя файла
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");// указываем MIME - тип
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path.$file)); //указываем размер

readfile($path.$file);//выдаем файл
```

[http заголовки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP)

[MIME типы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)